# Stadium Seating - Geometric Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

A circular stadium consists of sections as illustrated, with aisles in between. The diagram show the tiers of concrete steps for the final section, **Section K**. Seats are to be place along every step, with each seat being 0.45cm wide. AB, the arc at the front of the first row is 14.4m long, while CD, the arc at the back of the back row is 20.25m long.

$\hspace{2in}$ [image: stadium]

1) How wide is each concrete step?

2) What is the length of the arc of the back of Row 1, Row 2, Row 3, etc.?

3) How many seats are there in Row 1, Row 2, Row 3, ……, Row 13?

4) How many sections are there in the stadium?

5) What is the total seating capacity of the stadium?

6) What is the radius of the ‘playing surface'?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please review [ask] for ways to improve your Question.  As it currently reads, you have multiple parts with no indication of where you may be having difficulty, and there's no context to motivate why the problem is interesting.  The "edit" link below the Question can be used to improve it.

Comment: A geometric sequence is something like $a, ar, ar^2, ar^3, \ldots$. There are no such things to be seen anywhere in this problem.

Comment: Maybe you can get extra credit for proving the geometry in the diagram is wrong. It is not possible to have two 32-degree circular arcs of length 14.4 and 20.25 such that the difference between their radii is 13. Why?

Comment: @DavidK The discovery that the data are not consistent is nice. Would like to know “was the inconsistency found by full computations or by noticing some irregularities of the combination of numbers”?

Comment: @Mick  I forget the exact moment I noticed this, but I think it was while contemplating the radius of the 14.4-meter arc. The four measurements are redundant (any three of them would be sufficient to compute the fourth measurement _and_ also compute $r$). Where you have redundancy you have a chance for inconsistency. It also seemed that there should be a factor of $\pi$ (or at least an approximation of it) in at least one measurement, and it seemed to be missing.

Comment: @DavidK  Good point – redundancy could induce inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

First of im new here.

but the answer to question number one whould be (without actually writing all the numbers) The first step is obviously 14.4m wide and every step afther that is the widht of the one before him incremented by 0.45 ending with step 13 with a width of 20.25m

The calculation : (20.25 - 14.4) / 13

The answer of the 3th question whould be starting with row one 32 seats every row has one seat more then the one in front of it there fore the last one has 44 seats

The answer to the 4th question : One section is 32 degrees we need a circle so 360degrees therefore 11 sections

The answer to the 5th question : (i solved this one by writing a small java program) while (i < 13) {a++} ans  = 11 * a
The answer then becomes 5577 seats

I believe the answer to the 6th question whould be like this : ((11 * 14.4) / pi) / 2  =  50.4

I have not yet learned latex im working on that :)

Comment: Sometimes it's better to just do the math in a more "traditional" way, because there's obviously an error in how you programmed the question in Java and your use of the computer offers no easy way to detect the error. A little "traditional" math, however, says that if you know you have 32 seats per section in the first row, and 11 sections, that's already 352 seats. And the other rows have more. By the time you count up the first three rows you already have more than 934 seats, so that is not even close to the total capacity.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct its a stupid mistake as well, though the error is easy. by doing a++ i incremented a by one instead of taking 32 + 33 etc. Thank you for this correction.

Comment: For those intrested in the java code  i did it like this :

    package maths;

public class math {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Integer i = 0;
  Integer a = 32;
  Integer seats = 0;
  while(i < 13)
  {
   a++;
   seats += a;
   i++;
  }
  Integer answer = seats * 11;
  System.out.println(answer);
 }

}

Comment: I was going to make another "correction" but then realized the question is underspecified: does each seat "occupy" an arc length of 45 cm along the front of the row, or along the back of the row? If it's measured along the back of the row then you get an extra seat for each row in each section.

Comment: Could you explain to me how that works ? if its the front of the row it gets 1 extra seat but in the back 2 ?

Comment: I meant that if the length of the arc along the front is 32 seat widths then the arc along the back is 33 seat widths (which is 1 extra seat when compared to 32 seats).

Comment: ah i see. That is a good question indeed

Comment: Rather than using a java script, we can say: $\frac {44+32}{2}\cdot 13 \cdot 11=5434$  That is the average number of seats per row, times the number of rows times the number of sections.